# how to directly merge github pull request to my private repo?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Here's my situation,

1. I have a private repo, say privateRepo, on my own server
2. I also make the private repo on GitHub as a public repo, say openRepo (like a mirror)
3. People can fork openRepo, makes changes, sends a pull request
4. if the request was accepted, I'd like to rebase it directly to my privateRepo instead of merging it to the openRepo
5. meanwhile, some commits can be submitted to privateRepo for people working directly on privateRepo

Because if I accept the merging on the openRepo, I have to update privateRepo from the openRepo, there is a circle and it's redundant, not good for conflicts resolving. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

What circle are you talking about? The flow with merging on openRepo and then syncing back to privateRepo is absolutely clear. You just have two remotes - `private` and `public`, you merge pulls in public, and then sync it to private. If you'd skip pull requests in openRepo, then it will deviate more and more from privateRepo. It would be a tricky job to sync them back again after a while. Also, if you do not keep your public repo up-to-date, people can base their work on old, stale commits. For example I will create my branch to fix a bug, while it has been already fixed by another pull request which is not merged. Also, it is unclear why do you need a public repo if you will not accept pull requests in it?

I understand that you may want to hide some parts of your code hidden from the plebs. You can have dozen of branches in privateRepo for it, not being published to openRepo!

Comment: I'm talking about the graph in the middle of this [flow](http://wiki.apache.org/cordova/ContributorWorkflow). I didn't figure out why and how they merge request directly to privateRepo

Comment: Can you highlight the action, you are talkling about?

Comment: in the graph the pull request was merged into apache(guess it's private) instead of github repo. I don't know how and why they did that way. Usually the pull request is first merged back to upstream on github. I got similar workflow

Comment: Seems like it is not public repo, but kind of main Apache repo, "the only source of truth". They use github only for community relations, but Apache private is the primary one. I guess they have hooks to automatically sync repos. So, when they merge into "private", the changes are automatically synced to their github in a second.

Comment: I guessed too. I have similar situation. The private repos are primary repos, so pull requests are first merged into privates. But I don't know how to hook into github to merge/rebase pull requests into privates. Does github allow that? This is why I asked the question

Comment: Git allows to fetch changes from any source, e.g. `git fetch https://github.com/user/repo.git` without adding `user/repo.git` as a remote.